# Div opaqueness descending into the inner text?

Tags: html, css

I have a weird issue as I'm trying to follow the design of a mockup. I'm trying to figure out why the text below doesn't look white to me. It's inside an opaque `div`.

[image: illusion?]

Using Inspect Element I've verified that the text inside is not inheriting the `div`'s opaqueness and has its color set to white. So why does it look greyish to me? And how can I change it to *look* white (since it apparently *is* white)?

Here's the Inspect Element results for the "Not sure how to get started?" text:

```
element {
}
div.not-sure-inside h3 {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
div.not-sure-inside h3, div.not-sure-inside p {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
div.not-sure-inside a, div.not-sure-inside h3, div.not-sure-inside p {
    color: #FFF;
}
H3 {
    color: #0078AE;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
BODY {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

And for the div that contains it:

```
element {
}
div.not-sure-inside {
    float: left;
    width: 205px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FDB913;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin: 0px;
}
BODY {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Here's the mockup design (bonus points to anyone who knows how to make that triangle on the right):

[image: mockup]

Comment: It's because the whole div will be transparent, including the text. So it isn't weird; it's just like it has to be.

Comment: @Siyah is right. if u have any misunderstandings , give a  html code or make a jsfidle, that helps to analyze alot

Answer (score 3):

Instead of giving your entire div (including text) a lower opacity, you can style the background to only be transparent by using an rgba value such as:

```
div.not-sure-inside {
    float: left;
    width: 205px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(253, 185, 19, .8);
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

RGB of "253, 185, 19" = #FDB913

A of ".8" = opacity: .8

Comment: If you want a background for older browsers (like IE6 - 8), use: `background: #FDB913; background: rgba(253, 185, 19, 0.8);`. The old browsers will render the first color without transparency as they will not render the rgba.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
div.not-sure-inside {
    float: left;
    width: 205px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(253, 183, 18, .8);
    margin: 0px;
}
```